# Verilog: Implement a Pipeline hardware using flipflops

Tags: verilog, hardware, system-verilog, flip-flop

How to create a simple one stage pipeline in Verilog?

Answer (score 0):

## The easiest way to create a single state pipeline is create two always block synchronized with piped input(in_pipe) as given below. This work because of how the events are queued in the simulator time cycle.

```
module pipeline (reset,in,clock,out)

input reset, input, clock;
output out;`

logic reset, input, clock;
reg out, in_pipe;

always @(posedge clock or negedge reset)
 begin
  if(reset)
   begin
   in_pipe <= 0;
   end
 else
   begin
   in_pipe <= in;
   end
 end

always @(posedge clock or negedge reset)
begin
 if(reset)
  begin
  out<= 0;
  end
 else
  begin
  out<= in_pipe;
  end
end
```

Comment: usually it is posedge for the clock. Negedge is a special conditions and could even be prohibited in some methodologies. it is related to synthesis.

Comment: You could simply you code to half the lines of code. And from that you could make it more generic to support N stages by adding approximately 16 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
module pipeline#(
   parameter PIPE_NUM = 2,
   parameter DATA_WIDTH = 32 
)(
  input clock,
  input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]data_in,
  output [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]data_out
);

 //synthesis translate_off
 initial begin
   if(PIPE_NUM < 1) begin
       $fatal("Error: PIPE_NUM must be greater than 0!");
   end 
 end 
 //synthesis translate_on

 reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]pipeline_reg[PIPE_NUM-1:0]/*synthesis preserve*/;

 assign data_out = pipeline_reg[PIPE_NUM-1];

 integer p;
 always @(posedge clock)begin
    pipeline_reg[0] <= data_in; 
    for(p = 1;p < PIPE_NUM;p = p+1)begin
       pipeline_reg[p] <= pipeline_reg[p-1];
    end
 end 

endmodule
```